# Execute statements for every record in a table

Tags: t-sql

I have a temporary table (or, say, a function which returns a table of values).

I want to execute some statements for each record in the table.
Can this be done without using cursors?

I'm not opposed to cursors, but would like a more elegant syntax\way of doing it.

Something like this randomly made-up syntax:

```
for (select A,B from @temp) exec DoSomething A,B
```

I'm using Sql Server 2005.

Comment: Be more specific. Right now your question is answerless

Comment: I have a stored proc: DoSomething which takes a varchar(255) as a parameter. I want to 'select [name] from foomaster where id < 100' and execute DoSomething for each [name] that is returned. But it looks like cursors are the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think what you want to to is that easy.

What i have found is that you can create a scalar function taking the arguments A and B and then from within the function execute an Extended Stored Procedure. This might achieve what you want to do, but it seems that this might make the code even more complex.

I think for readibility and maintainability, you should stick to the CURSOR implementation.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I've looked around and cursors are pretty much the standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into changing the stored proc so that it can work against a set of data rather than a single row input.

Answer (score 0):

Would [`CROSS/OUTER APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) do what you want if you need [RBAR](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) processing.

It's elegant, but depends on what processing you need to do